# Python JSON dump accended characters

Tags: json, python-2.7

I'm using a program called Wrapper.py([this](https://github.com/benbaptist/minecraft-wrapper)), but there's some type of error. Becouse it's Python, I've tried to found the error. As far as I know, the error is at that it tries to write & load some JSON, but it receives strings like this: "Közép-európai nyelvezet", or something like this. It causes UnicodeDecodeError:

```python
>>>import json
>>>out={"a":"Közép-európai nyelvterület"}
>>>json.dumps(out)
Tracebank(the path, etc.)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0x94 in position 1: Invalid start byte
```

Then I googled, & found that solution for encoding:

```python
>>>a=json.dumps(out,ensure_ascii=False)
>>>a
'{"a":"K\x94z\x82p-eur\xarpai nyelvter\x81let"}'
```

Then I wanted to load it:

```python
>>>json.loads(a)
Traceback, etc.
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0x94 in position 1: Invalid start byte
```

```python
>>>json.load(a,ensure_ascii=False)
Traceback
TypeError: __init__() got an unespected keyword argument: 'ensure_ascii'
```

How can I load my data back?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use text instead of bytestrings.

```
out = {u"a":u"Közép-európai nyelvterület"}
```